# How to change scrapy's duplicate filter behavior to still return an item?

Tags: python, duplicates, scrapy, web-crawler

I have the following urls:

```
BASE-URL | FOLLOW-URL
URL 1 ---> Link to URL 4
URL 2 ---> Link to URL 4
URL 3 ---> Link to URL 5
```

I am scraping the pages in the following manner:

1. I scrape everything on the BASE-URL.
2. I call a new scrapy request to scrape everything in FOLLOW-URL to add new data to the existing item from the referer request. In *parse_follow* I add all new information to the existing item:

   ```
   yield scrapy.Request(FOLLOW-URL, meta={'item' : item}, callback=self.parse_follow)
   ```

As URL 1 and URL 2 point to the same FOLLOW-URL, scrapy detects duplicates and drops one of them. Is it possible however to still return *item*, when there is a duplicate instead of entirely dropping it?

Comment: Simply add to your `scrapy.Request` argument `dont_filter=True`.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning that I've done this. But does it not compromise tremendously with the performance of the scraping? I have around 40.000 BASE-URLs.

Comment: Do you need to yield an item containing data from the follow-url page? If so, you'll need to use the `dont_filter=True` as suggested bij vold. Otherwise you _could_ consider to create a Set() and add scraped urls to this set. Only yield a request for the follow url if the follow url is not in the set.